# How to catch Jersey 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: jersey

How do I prevent Jersey from spewing an HTML page at the client when the client requests an unacceptable MIME type? I would like to use `ExceptionMapper`, but I'm not sure what exception to catch, or if this is the best way to handle 406's.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have control over the client side ?

Your client accepts a list of MIME types. If your server **cannot** produce the requested MIME type, then it makes sense to return a 406 HTTP. What else would you want the server to do ?

If you know what MIME type the client is requesting, AND if the method on the server side is able to produce the requested type, you can modify your @Produces annotation to allow the server to serve the desired content.

EDIT : I don't have a simple solution (that could involve ContainerRequestFilter) at hand, but maybe you can have this very simply , if you use tomcat, but setting a custom error page, with a simple content

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>406</error-code>
    <location>whatever you want</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: I agree - I *want* to return a 406. What I don't want is a spew of HTML - I just want to return an error code and maybe a custom message. What I'm asking is: what is the best way to customize the response format for 406..`ExceptionMapper`? I see that newer versions of JAX-RS (2.0) have a [`NotAcceptableException`](http://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/NotAcceptableException.html). Don't see anything equivalent for 1.x.

Comment: I edited the answer, with no real solution, but a possible workaround instead

Comment: Hm..hadn't thought of that. This is an API so for most responses we return an error code with a more informative message, but for 406 this could actually work nicely. Will try it out.

Comment: another way would be to accept all MIME types, and to use @Context final HttpServletRequest request to get the httpRequest and manually check for the accept list. But it's probably even worse as you bypass a very interesting feature of jersey.